# vim tabular only on the first match on the line?

Tags: vim, formatting, format, tabular

I'm trying to format some python code with the tabular.vim plugin. It's currently a sqlalchemy declarative class, and looks something like this:

```
id     =  db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
status    =  db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False, default=3)
...etc...
```

I'd like to be able to align only the very first equals sign in the list.

```
id     =  db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
status =  db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False, default=3)
...etc...
```

Just a regular

```
: Tabularize /=
```

seems to match everything, and everything goes crazy.

Thanks very much in advance!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use this command:

```
:Tabularize /^[^=]*\zs=
```

The pattern only matches the first `=`.

---

You can add these two line to `~/.vim/after/plugin/TabularMaps.vim`

```
AddTabularPattern 1=    /^[^=]*\zs=
AddTabularPattern 1==   /^[^=]*\zs=/r0c0l0
```

---

Next time, simply run:

```
:Tabularize 1=
```

If you don't need spaces around `=`, run this:

```
:Tabularize 1==
```

---

Comment: This isn't vim builtin function, isn't it ?

Comment: Nope, it's part of the Tabular plugin:
https://github.com/godlygeek/tabular,
http://vimcasts.org/episodes/aligning-text-with-tabular-vim/

Comment: So... how can I handle the last match of the line? I've tried to aligh the final `,` via `/.*,[^,]*\zs`, but doesn't work

Answer (score 22):

The suggestions above are good, but in this case they are a little too complicated and require too much typing.  How about:

```
:Tab /=.*/
```

This works just fine -- match the first equal sign and everything after it, aligned left (default, which works just fine!).

Answer (score 7):

Excellent plugin to do it: [vim-easy-align](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-easy-align).

Answer (score 2):

As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20435920/dynamic-vim-tabular-patterns), instead of creating a static mapping for each case, you can do this dynamically by setting up a vim command like this:

```
command! -nargs=1 -range TabFirst exec <line1> . ',' . <line2> . 'Tabularize /^[^' . escape(<q-args>, '\^$.[?*~') . ']*\zs' . escape(<q-args>, '\^$.[?*~')
```

With this command, if you wanted to align based on the first `=` then you could do:

```
:TabFirst =
```

Or, if you wanted to align on the first `{` you could do:

```
:TabFirst {
```

This supports range selections as well as Tabularize's smart selection.

Comment: This seems to be the better answer.