# Dynamic vim Tabular patterns?

Tags: vim, formatting, format, tabular

I've seen many ways of creating vim Tabular patterns for a specific predetermined pattern. For example, in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11497961/254046) I see a mapping for:

```
AddTabularPattern 1=    /^[^=]*\zs=
```

Which allows you to do:

```
:Tabularize 1=
```

The regex above is hardcoded to match on the first equals character. Is there any way to define an arbitrary character instead, so that I could create a pattern that matches any character?

For example, I'd like to be able to do the following to match on the first "|" or the first "}" without having to create a separate predefined pattern for each.

```
:Tabularize 1| 
:Tabularize 1}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible directly via Tabular. However, you can define a wrapper command that accepts the desired string as an argument:

```
command! -nargs=1 First exec 'Tabularize /^[^' . escape(<q-args>, '\^$.[?*~') . ']*\zs' . escape(<q-args>, '\^$.[?*~')
```

You can then execute `First` with any character, e.g. `:First =` and `:First |`, or even longer strings, e.g. `:First ||` and `:First &&`.

In case this better suits your use case, you can also define mappings that use the current selection (in normal mode, the character under the cursor) as the argument:

```
vnoremap <F3> y \| :exec 'Tabularize /^[^' . escape(getreg('"'), '\^$.[?*~') . ']*\zs' . escape(getreg('"'), '\^$.[?*~')<CR>
nnoremap <F3> yl \| :exec 'Tabularize /^[^' . escape(getreg('"'), '\^$.[?*~') . ']*\zs' . escape(getreg('"'), '\^$.[?*~')<CR>
```

**Edit:** In order to allow for ranges, add the `-range` attribute to the command definition and pass `<line1>` (beginning) and `<line2>` (end) on to `Tabularize`:

```
command! -nargs=1 -range First exec <line1> . ',' . <line2> . 'Tabularize /^[^' . escape(<q-args>, '\^$.[?*~') . ']*\zs' . escape(<q-args>, '\^$.[?*~')
```

Comment: I tried the first solution, and while it's very clever, it unfortunately doesn't seem to work when you have range selections, which is the main way I use Tabular.

Answer (score 1):

[easy-align](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-easy-align) plugin allows you select a specific occurrence of the delimiter in the lines.

```
" around 1st =
:EasyAlign=
" around 2nd =
:EasyAlign2=
" around all =
:EasyAlign*=
" around the last =
:EasyAlign-=
```

Likewise,

```
" around 1st :
:EasyAlign:
" around 2nd :
:EasyAlign2:
" around the second to last |
:EasyAlign-2|
" around all whitespaces
:EasyAlign*\
```

Notice that `=`, `:`, or `|` are not regular expressions but ["delimiter keys"](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-easy-align#concept-of-alignment-rule), which you can think of as 1-character shortcuts for common alignment tasks.

Of course you can use regular expressions as well by surrounding the pattern with slashes

```
" around 1st <>
:EasyAlign/<>/
" around all <>
:EasyAlign*/<>/
```