# how can I tabularize paragraphs with space as the only separator

Tags: vim, nagios

I have following nagios config snippet. I could not come up with tabularize command to tabularize parameter values which are only separated by tabs/spaces.

```
define service{
    use                             local-service,srv-pnp         
    name        http
    service_description             http
    check_command     check_http!-w 5 -c 10 -H www.kpoint.com -u /
    register      0
}
```

EDIT:

The expected output is

```
define service{
    use                   local-service,srv-pnp         
    name                  http
    service_description   http
    check_command         check_http!-w 5 -c 10 -H www.kpoint.com -u /
    register              0
}
```

Is there any alternative to tabularize?

Comment: What do you want to do?

Comment: Please include the expected result; your failed attempts would provide insight, too.

Comment: This one worked. 

   :Tab /^\s*\w*

[Credit goes to this post][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11497593/vim-tabular-only-on-the-first-match-on-the-line

Comment: @ManishSapariya you almost had it right. `:Tabularize/^\s\+\w*/` Please post this as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following command does the trick.

```
:Tabularize /^\s*\w*
```

[The link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11497593/vim-tabular-only-on-the-first-match-on-the-line), though does not answer the exact question, has the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Very dirty and quickly way to do it:

```
function! GetOffsetSpacesAndReplace()
    let [line1,col1] = getpos("'<")[1:2]
    let [line2,col2] = getpos("'>")[1:2]
    let max_len = 0
    for i in range(line1, line2)
        let my_line = getline(i)
        let matching_str = matchstr(my_line, '^\s*\w*\s*')
        if len(matching_str) > max_len
            let max_len = len(matching_str)
        endif
    endfor
    for i in range(line1, line2)
        let my_line = getline(i)
        let matching_str = matchstr(my_line, '^\s*\w*\s*')
        let col_pos = len(matching_str)
        call setpos('.', [0, i, col_pos, 0])
        let @s=' '
        if max_len - col_pos > 0
            execute 'normal! "s'.(max_len - col_pos).'p'
        endif
    endfor
    return 1
endfunction

vmap <silent> <buffer> <F3> :call GetOffsetSpacesAndReplace()<CR>
```

This function allow you to select visually the inner block and then run the function to indent as you wished.

This is dirty mostly because it answer only your requirements.

In order to use a more flexible tool to do indentation, you should probably check the excellent plugin [vim-easy-align](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-easy-align).

I'm using it every day without any problems.

Comment: @SteveC A link to the mentioned package is hardly against the rules :).

Comment: You're right. I did a little very dirty and quick script to answer the question. But kept the fact that the plugin will be more flexible :)